# How to use && in foreach in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach

```
   $videoskey_list = explode(',',$result[$x]["videos_key"]);
   $videosname_list = explode(',',$result[$x]["videos_name"]); 

   foreach($videoskey_list as $videoskey => $videos_key && $videosname_list as $videosname => $videos_name) 
    {
        echo '  <button id="playtrailer" class="playtrailer" data-src="'.$videos_key.'"> '.$videos_name.' </button>';
    }
```

How do i use && in foreach. It should work, right? Or PHP do not support && in foreach?

Error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND),

Comment: No it doesn't!!

Comment: what? why would you do that....  && is a boolean comparison operator.  Foreach takes an array as input...

Comment: Use the key of `$videoskey_list` to access the other array, you can't pair multiple arrays in a `foreach`.

Comment: The real issue here will come if those 2 arrays are not in sync, because there is no direct relationship between them, you could have a situation where one is longer then the other or the order is wrong.  This may not be possible in your case but it's something to consider.  It seems problematic to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your keys and values are both means this should be work...

```
$videoskey_list = explode(',',$result[$x]["videos_key"]);
$videosname_list = explode(',',$result[$x]["videos_name"]);
foreach( $videoskey_list as $index => $videos_key ) {
   echo '  <button id="playtrailer" class="playtrailer" data-src="'.$videos_key.'"> '.$videosname_list[$index].' </button>';
}
```

EDITED:
If we use `array_combine` The both array should be equal. Here We can use How many keys we have that much Output will get here.

In `array_merge` The both arrays are merged so we can't fine the same key and value.

Explanation For this Answer:

First we get an videoskey_list As key and Value.
If match the Key with the Value. We can use videoskey_list's key as videosname_list's index. For example check [here](http://www.writephponline.com/) with this code.

```
$numbers = array('1','2','3');
$alpha = array('a','b','c');
foreach( $numbers as $index => $number ) {
  echo $number .'->'. $alpha[$index] .'<br />';
}
```

Comment: Its wrong where you have define `$videoskey_list` @JoshPoor

Comment: @RJParikh No this just works like an `array_combine`  But here the key is the main role so if we depend key means no problem in array_combine if don't have equal array it throws an error.

Comment: Your case will only work if `$videoskey_list` and `$videosname_list` both have same number of array values. If its different then its not work.

Comment: Hahaha Array_combine is also the same problem @RJParikh .In an array, combine wants equal array but here we can use how many keys we have and execute well.

Comment: Ok, I have checked its work if we use array_merge() and its not working with array_combine().

Comment: Yes, Perfect ! +1

Answer (score 4):

```
$videos_list = array_combine($videoskey_list, $videosname_list);
foreach($videos_list as $key => $name) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: array combine can be difficult, it will blowup if the arrays are not the same size, that said your code is not technically wrong I would just count both arrays first  `if( count( $videoskey_list ) == count( $videosname_list ) )` and handle errors as needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_combine()`

```
$videoskey_list = explode(',',$result[$x]["videos_key"]);
$videosname_list = explode(',',$result[$x]["videos_name"]); 

foreach (array_combine($videoskey_list, $videosname_list) as $videos_key => $videos_val) {
    echo '  <button id="playtrailer" class="playtrailer" data-src="'.$videos_key.'"> '.$videos_val.' </button>';
}
```

**OR**

Use `array_merge()`

```
foreach (array_merge($videoskey_list, $videosname_list) as $videoskey => $videos_val) {
        echo '  <button id="playtrailer" class="playtrailer" data-src="'.$videos_key.'"> '.$videos_val.' </button>';
    }
```

**Demo**

```
<?php
$videoskey_list = array('111','222','333');
$videosname_list = array('test','abc','xyz');

foreach (array_combine($videoskey_list, $videosname_list) as $videos_key => $videos_val) {
  echo '  <button id="playtrailer" class="playtrailer" data-src="'.$videos_key.'"> '.$videos_val.' </button>';
}
```

**Output**

```
<button id="playtrailer" class="playtrailer" data-src="111"> test </button>  
<button id="playtrailer" class="playtrailer" data-src="222"> abc </button>  
<button id="playtrailer" class="playtrailer" data-src="333"> xyz </button>
```

**Demo Link: [Click Here](https://eval.in/824136)**

Comment: Error in both answers `Undefined variable: videos_name in `

Comment: I have edited answer. Just to pass it on foreach and use it like `$videos_val['videos_name']` @JoshPoor